# Perfectly centering text in multiple triangles in same div (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to preface this that I'm 100% good with a pure CSS solution to create the triangles and am only using an image because I don't know of a good way to create them with pure CSS that works great on all devices. I have added a Code Sandbox, but at the bottom of this post is the raw html/css.

Here's an image of what I'd like to create (don't worry about boxes with names in them)

[image]

I'm almost there, but I'm struggling to keep the text perfectly centered on the bottom left and bottom right triangles while resized. Here's a Code Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-beaver-1ex8s

When you resize the browser you'll see the text moves off center.

I am building an app in React and will be replacing a custom chart with this for branding purposes. As such, it must scale down for mobile and various devices. Here's a screenshot of where I'm at in my app and the chart getting replaced so you can see end-use:
[image]

Sincerely appreciate help!

styles.css

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    right: 66.6%;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 66.6%;
    /* transform: translate(-100%, -100%); */
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66.6%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="images/triangle.png" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%" />
            <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
            <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
            <div class="middle">Middle</div>
            <div class="centered">Centered</div>
        </div>

        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the text when the triangles are too small to accommodate it all on one line?

Comment: @AHaworth - I can scale that with break points. It'll just be 2 digit numbers with % so I'm not too worried about that for most mobile devices. It's the centering that's challenging for me now.

Comment: I should also add that for mobile it'll break down into a 100% width div and the content currently to the right will go beneath it.

Comment: @Paulie_D - i have made the adjustments

Comment: So you are OK with text-align center as you already have to do the horizontal centering, it's just the vertical you are worried about (your sandbox made me think the horizontal was a problem as things shrank).

Comment: @AHaworth it's actually the left-right horizontal. When you scale the width down you can see the text isn't centering on the edges properly. Vertically everything still looks good so I'd be fine at minimum just getting horizontal nailed down. If both vertical and horizontal can be perfectly centered that'd be ideal.

Comment: you may use vmin units,  grid, clip-path, then flex and some padding to adjust the text vertical offset . https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-johnson-ux21v?file=/styles.css

Comment: @G-Cyrillus This is awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, I had misinterpreted the problem. If you make the text holding divs 50% wide and position them at the start of their triangles then text-align: center; works so it's simpler than I had thought. I've put the altered CSS in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical alignment is OK, it's centering the text horizontally that is awry.

If we change the div holding the text so that each is 50% wide and is positioned at the left side of its triangle then `text-align: center;` will work. It's quite nice because it's simple and doesn't alter the HTML.

Here's the CSS

```
  .container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.container div {
  width: 50%;
  }

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 0;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66.6%;
    left: 25%;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could relay on vmin units to resize your box, and grid to draw the layout.

clip-path can be used to shape the triangles and finally flex and padding to center and offset text vertically .

[here is the idea](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-johnson-ux21v?file=/styles.css:0-923).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 98vmin;
  margin: auto;
}

.container>div {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  color: white;
}

.container>.bottom-left {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  background: #fec00f;
}

.container>.bottom-right {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 5 / span 4;
  background: #c02026;
}

.container>.middle {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  background: #3b3938;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}

.container>.centered {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  background: #70ae47;
}

html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

`clip-path`again and `grid-gap` might also allow you to draw borders(from the container background)  if you wish .

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 98vmin;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1vmin 1vmin 0.5vmin 1vmin;
  gap: 0.5vmin 1.5vmin;
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.container>div {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px #000
}

.container>.bottom-left {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  background: #fec00f;
}

.container>.bottom-right {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 5 / span 4;
  background: #c02026;
}

.container>.middle {
  grid-row: 5 / span 4;
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  background: #3b3938;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}

.container>.centered {
  grid-row: 1 / span 4;
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  background: #70ae47;
}

html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- you can include me inside another grid and decrease my vmin size to share it with other content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom-left">15%</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">10%</div>
  <div class="middle">15%</div>
  <div class="centered">60%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else is giving CSS hacks, but the real way to approach this is to get the math right. You are currently treating the image as though it's square, but it isn't.

For an equilateral triangle with side length L, the height of the triangle is h = sqrt(3)/2 * L. That means the image you're using is 2L wide and L*sqrt(3) tall, so your vertical percentages are off.

Additionally, the center of an equilateral triangle is L/sqrt(3) away from each of the vertices. Knowing that, the center of the triangle can be located at (L/2, L/sqrt(12))

For your small triangles, L = 50%, so the center of the bottom left triangle is 50%/2 from the left side of the image and and 50%/~3.464 from the right side of the image or 25%, 14.4%. Use the same values for bottom right, but set against right and bottom.

For the center triangle, the top of the triangle is at 50%, so for the center mark, top = 50% + 14.4% (or bottom = 50% - 14.4%). For the top triangle, top = 50% - 14.4% (or bottom = 50% + 14.4%)

Then use the transform: translate(-50%, -50%); to account for the size of the text itself.

```
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14.4%;
    left: 25%%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14.4%;
    left: 75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35.6%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 64.4%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably better ways of ding it, but one basic idea to get you started using ::before for the text.

```css
.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5em solid yellow;
}

.triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 5em solid transparent;
  border-top: 5em solid red;
}

.chart {
}

.chart div{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.chart div::before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  text-align: center;
}


.chart .top {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

.chart .left {
}

.chart .center {
  margin-left: -5.25em;  
}

.chart .center::before {
  margin-top: -5em;
}


.chart .right {
  margin-left: -5.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <div class="triangle-up top" data-text="10%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-up left" data-text="20%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-down center" data-text="30%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-up right" data-text="40%"></div>
</div>
```

Using vw

```css
.triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10vw solid yellow;
}

.triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 10vw solid red;
}

.chart {
}

.chart div{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.chart div::before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 11.5vw;
  font-size: 3vw;
  width: 10vw;
  margin-left: -5vw;
  text-align: center;
}


.chart .top {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.chart .left {
}

.chart .center {
  margin-left: -11vw;  
}

.chart .center::before {
  margin-top: -12vw;
}


.chart .right {
  margin-left: -11vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <div class="triangle-up top" data-text="10%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-up left" data-text="20%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-down center" data-text="30%"></div>
  <div class="triangle-up right" data-text="40%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would this work on mobile devices (responsive)? It looks like dimensions are hard-coded so it can't scale by width properly.

Comment: So use vh or vw